# Cross domain ajax to diversify requests to API service

Tags: ajax, api, cross-domain

I want to access data from an API service using a client-side web app. The service is the openFDA's new API: https://open.fda.gov/api/reference/

There is a 1000 request per day limit, 60000 with key. To diversify IP usage, would it be feasible to have the users send the requests to the FDA's service themselves, by making a cross domain ajax request? Are there other considerations that would make this a bad practice?

Thanks.

Comment: I think to make a CORs request the server has to be configured to accept such requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For building something entirely client-side, I would recommend not using a key and instead relying on the IP-based limits. openFDA supports CORS, so the requests will be coming from the visitor's IP address and your app won't be subject to app-specific restrictions.

Hope this helps!

Sean Herron, openFDA Core Team Member